# use php preg_replace to replace a specific pattern with a blank

Tags: php

I still haven't found a guide that can make me actually understand preg_replace, so I'd be glad if anyone could share a page with clear examples. For the life of me, I've been reading all this time, with no results. Cutting to the chase:

I am looking to use preg_replace to replace both of these two cases with a blank:

a) [gallery]
b) [gallery ids="X, XX, XXX, XXXX"]

Where X, XX, XXX, XXXX = any number without a specific number of digits. If anyone could help I'd appreciate it! Easy way for the people that know this kind of stuff to earn some site points!

Comment: Honestly? `/\[gallery(?: ids="\d+")?\]/` (assuming I understood your vague "X, XX, XXX, XXXX" thing correctly)

Comment: this is not working as expected... my current example of replacement is:  [gallery ids="1577,1578,1579,1580,1581,1582,1583"]

Comment: Okay, so replace `\d+` with `[\d,]+`

Comment: Yup this did it, post as an answer to give you the credit you deserve

Comment: Questions like this are essentially "givemetehcodez" and should not be answered on Stack Overflow, because they shouldn't be asked ;)

Comment: Well, I am going to read the page the following user has added and also will try to decode your piece of code, it's really helpful for me. Well, many of us have the right to answer a dum question every now and then! :D